# How to scan ipv6 enabled hosts on my LAN?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, ipv6, local-area-network

I want to discover all my neighbors who enabled ipv6 protocol and still alive. I tried `ip -6 neighbor show` but it shows nothing.

Can someone recommend a tool and show some examples? Thanks.

Comment: Is there actually any IPv6 traffic on your network?

Comment: Wireshark allows `ipv6` as a filter, which would be one way to look for ND/RA packets.

Comment: @Douglas Su - if you are happy with the answer below please mark it as a correct answer to award the author for the time spent trying to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Best to ping a special *all nodes on a link* multicast address - `ff02::1` - and wait for the responses:

```
~ $ ping6 -I eth0 ff02::1
PING ff02::1(ff02::1) from fe80::a11:96ff:fe04:50cc wlan0: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::a11:96ff:fe02:50ce: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.080 ms
64 bytes from fe80::1eaf:f7ff:fe64:ec8e: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.82 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from fe80::6676:baff:feae:8c04: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4047 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from fe80::5626:96ff:fede:ae5f: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4047 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from fe80::5626:96ff:fede:ae5f: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3049 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from fe80::6676:baff:feae:8c04: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3049 ms (DUP!)
[...]
^C
```

A couple of points here:

- you must specify the interface: `-I eth0`
- The responses are *link-local* addresses - they can easily be converted to your global address by replacing the leading `fe80:` with your subnet's prefix, e.g. with `2001:db8:1234:abcd:` if that's your subnet's prefix.

See http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-multicast-addresses/ipv6-multicast-addresses.xhtml for some other multicast addresses other than `ff02::1` that may be of an interest.

Comment: Personally I prefer to use `-c` to have the ping command stop automatically and `-n` such that it won't attempt reverse DNS, like this: `ping6 -c2 -n ff02::1%eth0`. Replacing the link local prefix with the global prefix will often give you the node's global address, but not always, it depends on the specific configuration.

Comment: "_The responses are link-local addresses - they can easily be converted to your global address by replacing the leading `fe80:` with your subnet's prefix, e.g. with `2001:db8:1234:abcd:`_" That's not necessarily true. IPv6 can have, and even requires if addresses other than the link-local address, multiple networks on the same interface, and the IID portions of the addresses do not even need to be remotely the same. You must have a link-local address, but you can also have multiple global and/or ULA addresses on the same interface, and none need have the same IID or even prefix length.

Comment: Is there a way to do this from Windows? Windows' ping doesn't seem to have a "-I" equivalent.

Comment: How do you remove the duplicates and only get the different ones?

Answer (score -6):

I used a free software by NirSoft, called network tools. It automatically loads all your network information and you don't need the black cmd box.

Comment: how awesome is that, i hope it's an electron app!!!!!111!

Comment: I would assume "the black cmd box" is much more helpful in _learning_ about a problem than any given black box software.